# i want to extract all the characters in an image seperately ..what is the best way todo this?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Take this as an example image:

[image: take this as an example image]

I want to fetch all the characters in an image and compare them with each other and finally save similar characters together.

Comment: you can try `https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/` tesseract to do the ocr.

Comment: i dont want to extract text.. i just want whatever character is their in the image

Comment: can you pls elaborate your question? and  give an example for it ?

Comment: i want to select all the character(alphabets/numbers/special characters) present in an image and put together all the similar characters together such as a bunch of "A", a bunch of "b" etc

Comment: yea so if you do the ocr and do the ordering of the characters after you extracted the text whats the harm in that ?

Comment: i tried performing ocr on my image(with image Preprossessing also) . but ocr resuts arent accurate enough for my problem.Hence i decided to go this way

Comment: well you should then first try and segment/detect out each character and then do an ocr it helps with the accuracy

Comment: its handwritten text in the image and its cursive.

Comment: Clarify your question. Show an example of output you are expecting so someone can invite you to try some algorithms. Try to provide some code you already tried and explain what you are not succeeding to do. Without that, currently the best answer is: use an OCR.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Which characters are similar to each other? `X` and `Y`? `M` and `N`? When we find the characters on your image are you going to suddenly say you now want to find them from a scanned image with confusing background? Are the fonts fixed? Please try harder!

Answer (score 0):

To Extract all the characters from Image Try:

```
import Image
from PIL import Image
from tesseract import image_to_string
print (image_to_string(Image.open('SampleImg.png')))
print (image_to_string(Image.open('SampleImg.png'), lang='eng'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)!

It very fast and simple.